# Servlet forward to jsp blank page

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

This is the code I used to connect to a MySQL database through a servlet page in java, I'm trying to forward the user from a registration page to either a thanks page or a registration error page

```
// Get parameters from the request
        String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String country = request.getParameter("country");
        // Check Mandatory Fields
        if(pass == null||uname == null||email == null){
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
            request.getRequestDispatcher("regerror.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);

        }

        else{
        //Establish connection to Database
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        String databaseURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/account";
        String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "root";

        try {
            Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, user, password);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR Connecting to DB: " + e);
            return;
        }

        //Insert SQL statement
        String insertStmt = "insert into account values ("
                + "'" + uname + "', "
                + "'" + pass + "', "
                + "'" + email + "',"
                + "'" + country + "'"
                + ")";
        // Execute the insert statement
        try {
            stmt.executeUpdate(insertStmt);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Insert into DB: " + e);
            return;
        }
        //Close the database connection


        try {
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: closing DB connection: " + e);
        }

    }
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher3 =
            request.getRequestDispatcher("thanks.jsp");
            dispatcher3.forward(request, response);
}
```

There is a registration form page that takes you to this servlet when you click a submit button, but when you click the submit button it only shows an empty page instead of taking me to either the "thanks.jsp" or the "regerror.jsp" page. The code seems to work when I remove the if, else statements and put a request dispatcher at the beginning of the page, so I know that the register jsp takes you to this servlet.

Comment: Can you post here the whole class or at least the whole method?

Comment: This is the whole class the only thing that I didn't include is the imports, here they are: `import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;`

Comment: You also didn't include class and method definitions. Looking at the code I have a suspicion that there might be some nasty bracket lying around that's causing you the trouble. You can always update your original post and include whole class so we can see more.

Comment: Thank you for replying I found out that the error was that I had the name of the table I inserted the query statement into was wrong. Sorry for the inconvenience